# Серверный fastcgi софт

Tags: сервер, c++, mysql

Какие либы лучше использовать для написание fastcgi софта на плюсах? Так же нужна работа с БД (mysql).

Comment: Статья на Хабрахабре: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/61532/.
Там есть ссылки на пару библиотек (это про fastcgi).

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI на C/C++:

- [fcgi_stdio](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/21#S3.1) (официальный SDK)
- [fcgiap](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/21#S3.2) (официальный SDK)
- [fastcgi++](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/) (альтернативный SDK)
- [cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/)